# How to obtain a random vector in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I need obtain a vector with `n` numbers disposed in random order in MatLab. How can I do it?

If I use, for example, `randi(10,1,10)`, I will obtain random values, but I have no garantee that all the numbers will be in the sequence.

For example:

I need a vector with all the numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, disposed in a random order, like in `2,5,3,6,8,10,4,7,9,1`.

Comment: `randperm(10)` perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't aleatory order imply sampling with replacement?

Comment: Also, thanks for teaching me a new word today. Since there are in fact 10-sided dice, do you happen to mean "random order" when you say "aleatory order", or do you actually mean "pertaining to dice"?

Comment: Sorry. I had a mistake. It is random order.  Thanks Benoit_11. It solved my problem.

Comment: I fleshed out his comment into a selectable answer with plenty of additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are looking for the [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) function. From the docs:

> `p = randperm(n)` returns a row vector containing a random permutation of the integers from 1 to `n` inclusive.

Your example would be `randperm(10)`.

There is an optional second argument that you could pass in to determine how many elements will be chosen. For example, `randperm(10, 5)` would choose five random numbers from 1 to 10.

You can also use the results of `randperm` to shuffle or select from an arbitrary vector. Say you wanted the numbers 101 to 110 in random order instead of 1 to 10:

```
nums = 101:110;
nums = nums(randperm(numel(nums)));
```